# Got Wrong Answer but output is correct in Google Kickstart task

Tags: java

My code is giving correct output of a kickstart question of but getting WA (wrong answer)

**Problem**

An arithmetic array is an array that contains at least two integers and the differences between consecutive integers are equal. For example, [9, 10], [3, 3, 3], and [9, 7, 5, 3] are arithmetic arrays, while [1, 3, 3, 7], [2, 1, 2], and [1, 2, 4] are not arithmetic arrays.

Sarasvati has an array of N non-negative integers. The i-th integer of the array is Ai. She wants to choose a contiguous arithmetic subarray from her array that has the maximum length. Please help her to determine the length of the longest contiguous arithmetic subarray.

*Input*

The first line of the input gives the number of test cases, T. T test cases follow. Each test case begins with a line containing the integer N. The second line contains N integers. The i-th integer is Ai.

*Output*

For each test case, output one line containing Case #x: y, where x is the test case number (starting from 1) and y is the length of the longest contiguous arithmetic subarray.

*Limits*

Time limit: 20 seconds per test set.
Memory limit: 1GB.
1 ≤ T ≤ 100.
0 ≤ Ai ≤ 109.

Test Set 1
2 ≤ N ≤ 2000.

Test Set 2
2 ≤ N ≤ 2 × 105 for at most 10 test cases.
For the remaining cases, 2 ≤ N ≤ 2000.

**mycode**

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
     
public class Solution {
     
    static int function(int [] arr, int l) {
        int max = 0;
        int count = 2;
        int d = arr[0] - arr[1];

        for (int p = 1; p < l - 1; p++) {
            int x = arr[p] - arr[p+1];
            if (x == d) {
                count++;
                if (p == l - 2) {
                    if (max < count) {
                        max = count;    
                    }
                }
            } else {
                d = x;
                if (max < count) {
                    max = count;
                    count = 2;
                }
            }
        }
        return max; 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)));

        int t = sc.nextInt();
        for (int itr = 0; itr < t; itr++) {
             
            int l = sc.nextInt();   
            sc.nextLine();
    
            String[] input = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
            int[] arr = new int[l];

            for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
                arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(input[i]);
            }
                        
            System.out.printf("Case #%d: %d\n",itr+1,function(arr,l));         
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

**Modified code**

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Solution {

    static long function(long[] arr, int l) {
        long max = 0;
        long count = 2;
        long d = arr[0] - arr[1];
        for (int p = 1; p < l - 1; p++) {
            long x = arr[p] - arr[p + 1];
            if (x == d) {
                count++;
                if (p == l - 2) {
                    if (max < count) {
                        max = count;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                d = x;

                if (max < count) {
                    max = count;
                }
                count = 2;
            }
        }
        return max;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
     
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)));
        int t = sc.nextInt();
        for (int itr = 0; itr < t; itr++) {

            int l = sc.nextInt();

            sc.nextLine();

            String[] input = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
            long[] arr = new long[l];
            for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
                arr[i] = Long.parseLong(input[i]);
            }

            System.out.println("Case #" + (itr + 1) + ": " + function(arr, l));
        }
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

*Screenshot of output*

[image: screeshot output]

Comment: Did you write the main function yourself or was it supplied?

Comment: You always need to reset `count` when `d != x` (so in your else-branch). Currently you're only doing it when you've found a longer sub array. That means if you have arithmetic sub arrays of e.g. lengths 3 and 2 then since `max` and `count` both have the value `3` when you hit the beginning of the second sub array you're continuing to increment `count` and eventually get the value `4`.

Comment: Please give an example of input for which your code gives the wrong result.

Comment: no i wrote it @jhon

Comment: i did it but still getting Wrong Answer although my o/p is correct @Thomas

Comment: its in the screenshot i attached with the question@tgdavies

Comment: Well, even if the tests you get have the correct results it might not work for all. The initial set of tests is meant to get you started but on the server more and more complex tests will be conducted - and at least one of those fails.

Comment: in this task single test case contains sample mini test cases and my code is giving correct ans for all cases and also for my custom test input, that means my algorithm is not wrong..it should pass all the test cases, any way can you find the mistake @Thomas

Comment: Well, I've already stated a potential mistake in my first comment, did you write a test for that? I'll help: let's assume we have consecutive 4 arithmetic sub-arrays of lengths 4, 3, 3, 3 - your code should result in max = 5 which would be wrong. Why? Because count is reset to 2 when the second array starts and is incremented to 3 but when the 3rd and 4th arrays start count won't be reset and thus it will be incremented to 4 and 5 - resulting in max = 5 at the end. Test array: [4, 3, 2, 1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 5, 3] (with arithmetic sub-arrays [4, 3, 2, 1], [1, 3, 5], [5, 6, 7] and [7, 5, 3]).

Comment: "that means my algorithm is not wrong." - apparently your algorithm or at least implementation _is_ wrong or otherwise all tests, even those you don't see, would pass (I'd say Google's tests being correct is much more likely than your algorithm being correct). That all tests you know of passed just means that you didn't think of all possible cases.

Comment: yeah as per first comment I did modification in my code is  but still getting WA it  For this Test array: [4, 3, 2, 1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 5, 3]  max will be 4 and my code is also giving 4

Comment: Check Out the updated code @Thomas